# Can one share buddhist jokes?

Tags: discussion, support

I found a cool buddhist joke and would like to share it with the community.

I'm asking here because i'm not sure if one is allowed to post such questions/answers on Buddhism SE.

The joke is not in violation with our *"be-nice policy"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jokes would be appropriate [in any chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism).

This site's main chat room has been nearly/unusually inactive in the past, but feel free to use it in future. Some other sites (for example [CodeReview.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)) have conversation in their chat room every day.

The chat room is basically unmoderated. Only a "be nice" policy more or less still applies, but if you want to talk about anything (jokes, work, family, the weather, whatever you like), in any format (e.g. dialog not just Q&A), then it's not off-topic in the chat room.

There are [already some jokes in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16249470#16249470).